# PhpStorm/PhpDoc type-hinting for return variable in a magical object

Tags: php, phpstorm, type-hinting, hint

I have a class test and it `getData` that returns an object variables that arise in the context of methods magically.

My question is how to properly ohintovat to IDE and phpdoc told was correct. I want to PhpStorm understand what his return as output variables. Does it?

```
class Test
{

    /**
     * @param $param
     * @return object
     */
    function getData($param)
    {

        // .......

        $data = (object)[
            'a' => 'aaa',
            'b' => 'bbb',
        ];

        return $data;
    }

}


$test = new Test();
$data = $test->getData('param');

echo $data->
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think you can without returning a known object like a class instance with public methods.

Comment: you're returning a stdclass object that's created on-the-fly. php storm doesn't execute as you write, therefore it has nothing to analyze for $data.

Comment: Is this return type is the same all the time? If so -- my only thought is to declare it somewhere else (in some file that will be used by IDE only) and use it as return type. No other ways -- neither PHPDoc or PhpStorm support this kind of dynamic classes (typehinting "on the fly").

Comment: use a seperate datastructure instead - this is either way not a good practice

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to solve it using en extra model class.

[image]